# Get only value, powerShell without key

Tags: powershell, mac-address

I use PowerShell to determine the mac-addresses for Ethernet as well as the WiFi... the mac-address will be used for verification purposes..

Per command I would love to retrieve only the value not the key and the value…
that I can store and verify the retrieved string with the known string.

Example:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-fi" | Format-List -Property MacAddress
```

will return the `MacAddress : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX`

What I want is only `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX`

Is there any filer I can apply without code ..workarounds….

Answer (score 1):

`Format-List` is not needed, just access the property directly. Like so,

```
(Get-NetAdapter -name "wi-fi").macaddress
01-23-45-67-89-AB
```

Sometimes an intermediate variable is needed instead of the shorthand above. Like so,

```
$wifi = Get-NetAdapter -name "wi-fi"
$wifi.MacAddress
01-23-45-67-89-AB
```

In case you got several adapters, `Select-Object` can be used to expand the desired property. Like so,

```
Get-NetAdapter | ? { $_.status -eq "up" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty macaddress
01-23-45-67-89-AB
01-23-45-67-89-CD
```

Comment: I tried to verify your solution, but it doesn't answer OP's entire question. `the mac-addresses for Ethernet as well as the WiFi`. Wi-Fi works great, but Ethernet does not with this solution.

Comment: The shortcut from first will equally work with the last example `(Get-NetAdapter |? Status -eq 'Up').MacAddress` (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Not to ruin vonPryz partially acceptable answer, but:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -Filter "AdapterType LIKE 'Ethernet 802.3'") | select -expand macaddress
```

This will give you all mac-adresses on your computer.

Or in a comma seperated list:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} | Select-Object -Expand macaddress) -join ","
```

Or in a new-Line list:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} | Select-Object -Expand macaddress) -join "`r`n"
```